# Updating the list/set to be iterated in a for loop

Tags: python, set, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I'm trying to make a set of primes using Sieve's method. But it seems that `prime = prime - set(range(2*n,N,n))` does not update the set `prime` in `for n in prime:`.

```
N = int(raw_input()) + 1
prime = set(range(2,N))

for n in prime:
    print n
    prime = prime - set(range(2*n,N,n))
```

For example, I input `N = 100`. The output is `1,2,3,...,100`, making the code super slow. What should I do to update the set consistently?

**Edit:**
A little deeper: Can you explain the difference between augmented and non-augmented assignments? Is there really no way I can accomplish with just one set? Because it just seems so naive and I can't quite believe such high-level language as Python cannot achieve this, since in C++ I can do it with just an array of boolean values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop evaluates the iterable expression just *once*. You are not altering `prime`, you are *rebinding* the name to a new object (the output of `prime - set(range(2*n,N,n))`, the `for` loop will never see that.

Note also that a `for` loop over a `set` will do so in arbitrary order; the numbers are *not* sorted. You could easily be handed a non-prime first.

If you used augmented assignment to alter `prime` in-place, however, you'll get an error message about altering the set while iterating:

```
>>> N = 50
>>> prime  = set(range(2, N))
>>> for n in prime:
...     print n
...     prime -= set(range(2 * n, N, n))
... 
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
RuntimeError: Set changed size during iteration
```

You'll have to loop directly over the `range()` and track non-primes instead:

```
non_prime = set()
primes = []

for n in range(2, N):
    if n in non_prime:
        continue
    non_prime |= set(range(2 * n, N, n))
    primes.append(n)
```

Demo:

```
>>> non_prime = set()
>>> primes = []
>>> for n in range(2, N):
...     if n in non_prime:
...         continue
...     non_prime |= set(range(2 * n, N, n))
...     primes.append(n)
... 
>>> primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

or you could use a `while` loop with a candidates set you empty:

```
candidates = set(range(2, N))
primes = []

while candidates:
    n = min(candidates)
    candidates -= set(range(2 * n, N, n))
    candidates.remove(n)
    primes.append(n)
```

but this requires looping over all of `candidates` each time to find the minimum value.

Note that you can further reduce the range of sizes by using `range(n * n, N, n)` here; all `2 * n` values past `2 * 2` would already have been eliminated, all `3 * n` past `3 * 3` as well, etc.:

```
>>> primes = []
>>> for n in range(2, N):
...     if n in non_prime:
...         continue
...     non_prime |= set(range(n * n, N, n))
...     primes.append(n)
... 
>>> primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

Last but not least, the common way to implement the sieve is to use a list of booleans to mark out non-primes:

```
sieve = [True] * N
sieve[0] = sieve[1] = False
primes = []

for (n, is_prime) in enumerate(sieve):
    if is_prime:
        primes.append(n)
        for n in range(n * n, N, n):
            sieve[n] = False
```

Comment: For the less experienced people here, can you explain what the following line does: `non_prime |= set(range(2 * n, N, n))` I'm familiar with the `set` and `range` but am more interested in the `|=` part. Thanks.

Comment: @elParaguayo: `set1 | set2` is a set union. `set1 |= set2` is an augmented set union; `set1` is updated in-place.

Comment: I still don't quite get it. Can you explain the difference between augmented and non-augmented assignments? Furthermore, is there really no way I can accomplish with just one set? Because it just seems so naive and I can't quite believe such high-level language as Python cannot achieve this, since in C++ I can do it with just an array of boolean values.

Comment: @LiHsingChen: Non-augmented assignment would not update the set in-place, but produce a new set object. You'd have to use an explicit [`set.difference_update()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.difference_update) call instead. I focused on answering your question using sets because that was what you wanted to know about. You can use a list of booleans in Python just fine, I'll add that to the answer.

Comment: @LiHsingChen: see [Fastest way to list all primes below N in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068372) for a great study of options to implement prime generators below N in Python.

Comment: Thanks! Great help there. Nice to know n*n was faster.